# Empty Address NodePort Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm installing the Argo CD ingress manifests on my primary controlplane node, but how do I tell the argocd-server service to expose ingress traffic to my 3 worker nodes (172.30.100.130, 172.30.100.131, 172.30.100.132)?

```
kubectl patch svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx -p '{"spec": {"ports":[{"nodePort": 30001,"name":"http","port":80,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":80},{"nodePort": 30002,"name":"https","port":443,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":443}]}}'
```

I patch the default ports ingress-nginx-controller service ports:

```
root@k8s-master01:~# kubectl describe ing argocd-server-ingress -n argocd
    Name:             argocd-server-ingress
    Labels:           <none>
    Namespace:        argocd
    Address:
    Ingress Class:    nginx
    Default backend:  <default>
    Rules:
      Host                              Path  Backends
      ----                              ----  --------
      internal.mydomain.com
                                        /   argocd-server:https (<none>)
    Annotations:                        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: true
                                        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: true
    Events:                             <none>

    root@k8s-master01:~# kubectl get svc -A
    NAMESPACE       NAME                                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
    argocd          argocd-server                             NodePort    10.99.199.55     <none>        80:32599/TCP,443:30000/TCP   11m
    argocd          argocd-server-metrics                     ClusterIP   10.99.249.116    <none>        8083/TCP                     11m
    default         kubernetes                                ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      14m
    ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller                  NodePort    10.98.121.229    <none>        80:30001/TCP,443:30002/TCP   12m
    ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-admission        ClusterIP   10.110.89.214    <none>        443/TCP
              12m
```

My Argo CD ingress manifest looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-server-ingress
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: "{{ argocd_ingress_dns }}"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: argocd-server
            port:
              name: https
```

I'm also changing the argocd-server service to type NodePort and patching the svc with

```
kubectl patch svc argocd-server -n argocd -p '{"spec": {"type": "NodePort"}}'

kubectl patch svc argocd-server -n argocd -p '{"spec": {"ports":[{"name":"http","port":80,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":8080},{"nodePort": 30000,"name":"https","port":443,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":8080}]}}'
```